# Need Help with Ubuntu installation on my Asus Vivobook S510UN

Tags: system-installation

Created a bootable USB Drive for Ubuntu installation and tried several times though F12 key to load the installation window but nothing comes up. Has anybody faced similar issue? pls help!

Comment: How did you create the USB drive? Are you dual booting windows, if so did you turn off secure boot in windows, and shutdown instead of hibernating? Did you turn off secure boot and fast boot in your bios?

Comment: hey bud! thanks for the help. i just got help with that part but still not able to install it due to partition issues. Since im new to this, im having issues with partition selection and not proceeding further bec of my curiosity of loosing data or deleting drives. Any help for that would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is that a question? You have to help others to help you, by providing a concise description of your issue(s) with clear details, and output from system logs and/or diagnostic commands.